# Is there a way to validate CloudFormation templates before running them?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I would like to validate my CloudFormation templates before running them.  I know about the `aws cloudformation validate-template ...` cli command, but that ignores incorrect property names.  I don't know what the point of that cli command is if it won't catch these kind of mistakes.

I want something that will catch those kind of mistakes before running the templates.  An IDE or external service that does this would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

We had a quite similar issue with erroneous Cloud-Formation templates and created (I’m a co-author) a command-line tool, that validates them - besides the standard AWS validation it also has many custom checks, that were essential for us:

https://github.com/Appliscale/perun

I believe it doesn't support property names validation yet, but any feature requests (or pull request even better), are welcome. We will do our best to address them as soon as we can.

After installing Perun, to validate the template you can use the command **validate**:

`~ $ perun validate <PATH TO THE TEMPLATE>`

Moreover, it also allows managing (creation, updates etc.) CF stacks and monitoring the status updates.

Comment: Last commit was a year ago, is it still maintained?

Answer (score 2):

The [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) tool was built for this exact purpose. It is actively maintained by the AWS team and [it has a couple of IDE integrations](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint#editor-plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with me. There is no way to validate the property name. But you can reduce the mistake using Atom IDE with plugins cloudformation, it helps me to create a resources property so I can reduce my typo mistakes.